# Recommended libraries for building an app which includes for deep linking and oauth

Tags: react-native

I have recently started to build a react-native app, which I want to build for both iOS and Android using a firebase Backend, and Branch.io/Firebase deep-linking services. I want to include in it both OAuth provided by Google and some kind of invitation link by using deep-linking. I have encountered problems in finding a way of supporting both.
It is worth mentioning that I am new to React and javascript, and have no experience in it.

I have tried using react-native-cli and tried to add OAuth to Google using firebase. I couldn't find enough documentation, so I followed a tutorial on youtube, and only managed to make it work by switching to Expo instead of react-native-cli.

Then I tried implementing some kind of invitation to groups in my app, using deep linking. I tried firebase's Dynamic links but got an error that firebase.links() is not a function and couldn't solve it due to lack of docs about it.
I then found out about react-native-branch library. It is in Alpha version in Expo so in order to use the native module I found out that I had to detach from Expo, and I wonder if there's an easier way to do it.

I've spent several days, as expected, in order to try and solve those issues. Is there a relatively simple way to do it?